# How to remove duplicate EventReceiver entries

Tags: powershell, event-receivers, duplicate, delete

Lately i had a bug that time-to-time added duplicate event receiver entries in SPEventReceiverDefinitionCollection.

So how do i easily enumerate and remove these duplicate entries?

Comment: [I'm providing this question-answer for reference for myself and others.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Answer (score 5):

```
$eventReceiversToDelete = $list.EventReceivers | 
    group-object assembly, class, type | #Groups event receiver by assembly/class/type
    ? { $_.Count -gt 1 } |    #If any of assembly/class/type pairs are encountered more than once, we have a duplicate
    % { $_.Group[1..100] }  #enumerate starting from second item (indexed at 1), so we don't delete event receiver completely

for ($i = $eventReceiversToDelete.Count - 1; $i -ge 0; $i--) {
    Write-Host "Deleting $($eventReceiversToDelete[$i].Type) Event Receiver $($eventReceiversToDelete[$i].Name)" }
    #Uncomment to delete
    #$eventReceiversToDelete[$i].Delete()
}
```

Thanks to this blog post for showing the way: [Finding (and Deleting) Duplicate Files](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2009/01/11/finding-and-deleting-duplicate-files.aspx)

Comment: Great answer, was just about to start writing this PS myself so you've saved me time :-)

Comment: Getting this error "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute"

Comment: @Adam I tried to fix the script. Try to delete now. The problem is Foreach cannot be used for deletion - you must loop backwards within the collection to delete the entries. I haven't tested that script and hopefully no syntax errors there.

Comment: I ended up using a similar flavor to the change you made.  It should work provided the syntax is correct.  Thanks @JanisVeinbergs